# wurfl: How to configure wurfl_patch.xml in web.xml?

Tags: tomcat, wurfl

In my application , I created a wurfl_patch.xml file in WEB-INF folder.But there is another patch file web_browsers_patch.xml also exists. I configured these files as like below.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>wurfl</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/wurfl-2.3.3.zip</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>wurflPatch</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/web_browsers_patch.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Can i configure wurfl_patch.xml as follows

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>wurflPatch</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/wurfl_patch.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

in same param name wurflPatch ?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just replace /WEB-INF/web_browsers_patch.xml with /WEB-INF/wurfl_patch.xml